# speed with the use of regexps

Tags: python, regex, performance, profiler

Task: there is a volume of text files on the order of 30K daily. How to find out the speed of the program extracting entities using regular expressions (their number is about 20)?

The program is planned on Python. But the operating system and hardware will be determined based on the optimal performance of such a program. At this stage, we need information about the minimum possible configuration for extracting data "on the fly" and approximate figures for the speed with this configuration –

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: we'll need a lot more information to help.  What language, what have you tried, what operating system, what is the hardware like...

Comment: The program is planned on Python. But the operating system and hardware will be determined based on the optimal performance of such a program. At this stage, we need information about the minimum possible configuration for extracting data "on the fly" and approximate figures for the speed with this configuration

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd write up your regex in python, get 30k test files (same file copied 30k times?), see how long it takes to process.  And then use cProfile in python to profile the code for 1 file to see where you can speed it up.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! 30k files different